# Rails: :before_return?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This question has probably been asked before, but I was wondering if there was a mechanism that allows me to to the opposite of `:before_save`?

eg

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_return :split_tags

    def split_tags
        self.tags = self.tags.split(',')
    end

end
```

I am saving tags of MyObject into a database, separated by commas. When asking for the MyObject back from the database, I'd like the tags to become an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the getter:

```
def tags
  self["tags"] ? self["tags"].split(',') : []
end
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted. Had no idea it was that easy!